# Decay of convolution with measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

In order to get some estimates of certain integral my teacher has used the following lemma that, in his opinion it is trivial:

**Let us consider $\nu$ a radon measure  in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}d\nu=0$. If we define $F(x)=g*\nu(x)$ with $g(x)=\ln|x|$, then there exists $C>0$ such that $|F(x)|$ deacays like $C\frac{1}{|x|}$.**

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem so obvious to me. Does anyone know of any proof  a result like this?
I thought that I would get it by using Poincare's inequality, but it seems to me that it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.